# AdMob InterstitialAdd not showing in 8.0.0

Tags: android, admob

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{bible.bibleinbasicenglish/com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen activities can request orientation
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen activities can request orientation
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1888)
   at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.setRequestedOrientation(IActivityManager.java:5675)
   at android.app.Activity.setRequestedOrientation(Activity.java:5739)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.m.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:553)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.m.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:626)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.m.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:341)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.client.c.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:58)
   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:604)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzfv$zza$zza.onCreate(Unknown Source:27)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:24)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
```

here is the error log of Interstital ad when open app it will directall crash, i currently test add in the api Level 26, The error like Only fullscreen activities can request orientation , idont know why this is happening.

is there any soluthion for this ? then help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just simply add this line in your gradle file

```
targetSdkVersion = 26
```

Comment: To hide the problem is not a solution

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**

the newer (above 16) admob version fixed the issue

**Old Answer**

add this in your manifest

```
<activity
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
  tools:replace="android:theme"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

If your target SDk version >= 27 then you get this error so try to add below code

```
void setRequestedOrientation(int requestedOrientation) {
    if (ActivityInfo.isFixedOrientation(requestedOrientation) && !fullscreen
            && appInfo.targetSdkVersion > O) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Only fullscreen activities can request orientation");
    ....
    }
```

for more check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46995624/6834114)

Comment: i am using this : compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'