# “IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen activities can request orientation

Tags: android, ads, android-glide, recyclerview-layout, target-sdk

i'm tyring to update **Glide** library from **3.8.0** to **4.5.0** but i have this problem with `recyclerview` when i add `com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0` to my Build.Gradle file i get this error in `recyclerview` compile line .

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.0.2, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 and com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0.
```

i decided to update targetSdkVersion from 26 to 27 and it's works but when i run my app in Device with android 26 i have this error and app crashes

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen activities can request orientation
                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityRecord.java:2189)
```

After some research found a solution, SDK should be 26,But if I do this I will get back to the same problem again.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "maa.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 43
        versionName "4.1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}
android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //notifications
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.vodyasov:amr:0.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.7'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.6-android'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I see two options. First one is control devices with Android O (this android has the error "Only fullscreen activities can request orientation") and verify if you can change their behivor, or find a glide version that use the same support library version. If your problem on android O is with AdMob you can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992843/interstitial-admob-ads-illegalstateexception-only-fullscreen-activities-can-r/46995624#46995624)

Answer (score 0):

It was issue with Android version 8.0 (API 26)

I solved by using below approach
 add this code in manifest

```
  <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            tools:replace="android:theme"
            />
```

and in res/styles
add below code

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/StyledDialog1</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary1</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary1</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent1</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/fbutton_color_pomegranate</item>

        <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>

        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/popupMenuStyle</item>
    </style>
```

note: in res/style apptheme remove items if you dont use any

let me know if it helped you guys ! happy coding