# How to work around translucent layout params crash in Oreo?

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

I am starting a seperate activity to show a bottomsheet as [you can see here (click)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47512928/how-to-overhand-saveinstacestate-data-to-fragment-from-fragmentactivity).

Starting another `MyBottomSheetDialogContainerActivity` causes [this reported crash for Android 8.0](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68454482#comment37) devices. On Android 8.1 fixed.

There you can read, that the issue is obviously not fixed (for Android 8.0) and they propose to go back to targetSDK 26. Going back to targetSDK 26 solves the crash.

**Since we have an app online in Playstore, going back to targetSDK 26 is also not an option.**

How can I solve the issue, by setting the `translucent` property on the `BottomSheetContainerActivity` or similar?

Comment: "Since we have an app online in Playstore, going back to targetSDK 26 is also not an option." You can downgrade your targetSDK without a problem. We had a version targeting 27 on the Play Store and then we reverted to 26 in order to solve this very issue.

Comment: I am looking for a solution without downgrading anyway.

Comment: u can add few lines to manifest as in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48665610)