# SurfaceFlinger: Failed to find layer FullScreenFragmentActivity in layer parent (no-parent)

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottom-sheet, android-fullscreen

I have a `BottomSheetFragmentActivity` which [causes this crash on Android 8.0 devices](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68454482#comment37). I am looking for a workaround, without setting targetSDK back to 26.

I solved this [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992843/interstitial-admob-ads-illegalstateexception-only-fullscreen-activities-can-r/48665610#48665610):
But this in turn causes

> SurfaceFlinger: Failed to find layer BottomSheetFragmentActivity#0 in layer parent (no-parent).

**Is there a solution?**

Comment: now have you solved the issue? I also meet this question

Comment: @Ralf Wickum - Did you find an answer to this? Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
Clean Project -> Rebuild Project
```

or if it doesn't work

```
Invalidate Caches and Restart
```

Worked for me. Hope it helps.